# Groovy: How to write on a line on the same position on screen? (Windows)

Tags: groovy

I want to show advance % in groovy , so I want to write on the same position, which means that instead of seeing:

```
1%
2%
3%
...
```

The user will see the figures changing in the same location.
How do I do that? (I'm working on windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do this frequently just using a carriage return without a line feed:

```
printf "%5d\r", loopval
```

Each time through your loop, printing will start over again at the beginning of the line.

It can get a tad messy if any other messages should print out while this is happening, especially if the other message contain newlines.  But it's a cheap and dirty solution.

Comment: I can't get this to work on MacOS, the output is not overwritten but appended. Any ideas?

Comment: Works on OSX 10.8.5, groovy 2.2.1 JVM 1.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jline that comes with Groovy:

```
(1..5).each {
  print "Done $it of 5"
  Thread.sleep( 1000 )
  print jline.ANSIBuffer.ANSICodes.left( 9999 )
}
```

So long as your console supports ANSI escape sequences, that should work...

PS: I used 9999 because (as it says in [the documentation for left](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jline/ANSIBuffer.ANSICodes.html#left%28int%29))

> If n is greater or equal to the current cursor column, the cursor is moved to the first column

Comment: It doesn't seem to work very well, I'm getting this:
Done 1 of 5[9999DDone 2 of 5[9999DDone 3 of 5[9999DDone 4 of 5[9999DDone 5 of 5[9999D

Comment: What console are you using?  Windows?  If you're trying it in the Groovy console, that won't work either.

Comment: I'm working on windows - It gives the same result in the cmd prompt, in the Groovy console and in the Intellij Idea console output

Comment: None of those support ANSI escape sequences as far as I'm aware.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows_and_DOS

Comment: Didn't know that, Thanks! Any way to do it on a Windows?

Comment: There's things like this https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon but I haven't developed on Windows for years, so don't know how well (or indeed if) it works :-/

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this - I found using the following to be the best solution:

```
(0..100).each {
    print "\r$it%"
}
println()
```

Answer (score 1):

as Danny Y. already stated, a line feed will work, backspaces will also do the trick:

```
(0..100).each {
  print "\b"*20+it+"%"
  sleep 100
}
```

I once had to overwrite a multipline output - the solution I found was to

```
print "\r\n"*80
```

in order to scroll all old content out of the screen - not a nice solution, but it work on windows shell :-)